# MySQL Stored Procedure return value without a SELECT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getroom`(OUT `free_room` INT)
BEGIN

    SELECT room INTO free_room FROM admins WHERE free = 1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE admins SET free = 0 WHERE room = free_room;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to query the table for free rooms, lock the row so other users cannot query it at the same time, and set it as not free at the end.

My questions are:

1) How can I call a stored procedure and get the **free_room** value automatically (as if i ran a SELECT statement) without doing an additional SELECT statement?

2) Since I am not passing any arguments (don't have "IN" values), why can't I run `CALL getroom()` succssfully? I get the following error:

> Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE getroom; expected 1, got 0

Hope my questions are clear enough!

Comment: What's the point of this?

Comment: ad 2) note that the procedure really has one parameter - the one over which the result is returned. So, you need to call the procedure with `CALL getroom(@somevar)`. Afterwards, the result will be available in `@somevar`.

Comment: Ok, so the parameter is needed for the OUT value. For my first question, is there a way to `CALL getroom(@somevar)` and get a return value without having to do `CALL getroom(@somevar); SELECT @somevar;`?

Comment: try to create a FUNCTION having return statement to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create function instead:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `getroom`() RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE free_room INT;
    SELECT room INTO free_room FROM admins WHERE free = 1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE admins SET free = 0 WHERE room = free_room;
    RETURN free_room;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and then just use:

```
SELECT getroom();
```

Comment: This did the job! will it also row lock so it cannot be read by other users while it is updating?

Comment: Yes, the SELECT FOR UPDATE should lock the row, until it is updated with the next UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getroom`()
BEGIN 
    SELECT @free_room := room
    FROM admins
    WHERE free = 1
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE;

    UPDATE admins
    SET free = 0
    WHERE room = @free_room;   
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getroom`()
BEGIN 
DECLARE free_room INT;  
    SELECT room INTO free_room FROM admins WHERE free = 1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE admins SET free = 0 WHERE room = free_room;
    SELECT free_room;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```